# Windows 10 0xc00000e9 error on boot - but I can access that hard drive on my Linux partition

Tags: windows-10, boot

From what I have read, this error "File: \Boot\BCD" should only happen if my power supply is busted or the connection with the hard drive / hard drive itself is faulty. However, I can see all of the files fine from my Ubuntu partition that boots correctly. What do I need to do to fix this? Is there a way to boot Windows recovery from USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical errors are the connection cable or the drive itself.

If you are sure the drive is fine, you can get the manufacturer's recovery USB for your computer (best choice), or make a Windows 10 boot USB from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link. Boot with that to reinstall Windows.

Be aware the the Windows 10 install will likely check for drive errors. Just because you can read files (and of course should back these up), there still may be errors on the disk.

Try it and be prepared to replace the disk.

Comment: Is there a utility I can use to check the disk for errors on Linux? I tried to do the startup repair from the USB image but it was unable to fix it, does that mean I need to reinstall?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows 10 and everything worked

Comment: Good to know - thanks.